# Change font-size of an nav>ul>li>a element using nav tag of html5

Tags: css, html, font-size, nav

I face a problem setting custom font-size in css document. Here's my problem. I use nav tag of html5. Where do I have to place the font-size attribute?

Here's part of my codeQ

**Part of html code:**

```
<div id="nav">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">ΑΡΧΙΚΗ</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΕΣ</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">ΒΙΟΓΡΑΦΙΚΟ</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">ΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΑ</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

**Part of my css code:**

```
#nav {

    width: 30%;
    margin:0 auto;

}

nav>ul {
    list-style: none;       
}

nav>ul>li { 

    display: inline;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
    font-family: "Comfortaa Thin", Comfortaa;
    color:#807f7f;          
}
```

Comment: It can be anywhere inside the nav, or `#nav{font-size:20px}`.

Comment: It depends on your styles already defined. Because, for example. if you set #nav {font-size:20px} but you already have a selector for links (a {font-size: 12px}, it won't override it.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `font-size` to any container element including `nav` itself

```css
nav {
  font-size: 40px;
}
#nav {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
}
nav>ul>li {
  display: inline;
}
nav>ul>li>a {
  font-family: "Comfortaa Thin", Comfortaa;
  color: #807f7f;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">ΑΡΧΙΚΗ</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΕΣ</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">ΒΙΟΓΡΑΦΙΚΟ</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">ΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΑ</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav>ul>li>a {
    font-family: "Comfortaa Thin", Comfortaa;
    color:#807f7f;
    font-size: /*write here*/;          
}
```